# Does kafka metadata response alreays contains all brokers in cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, metadata

Kafka metadata response contains brokers metadata and topics metadata, Does brokers metadata always contains all brokers in the current cluster? Or only contains brokers related with topics in metadata request?

I trid with a v0 metadata request with one topic, there are far more brokers in metadata response then topic partition leaders and isr nodes and etc...

If there are relevant documents, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think Kafka protocol guide explains it clearly ([link](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_partitioning)):

> How can the client find out which topics exist, what partitions they
> have, and which brokers currently host those partitions so that it can
> direct its requests to the right hosts? This information is dynamic,
> so you can't just configure each client with some static mapping file.
> Instead **all Kafka brokers can answer a metadata request that describes
> the current state of the cluster: what topics there are, which
> partitions those topics have, which broker is the leader for those
> partitions, and the host and port information for these brokers.**
>
> In other words, **the client needs to somehow find one broker and that
> broker will tell the client about all the other brokers that exist and
> what partitions they host**. This first broker may itself go down so the
> best practice for a client implementation is to take a list of two or
> three URLs to bootstrap from. The user can then choose to use a load
> balancer or just statically configure two or three of their Kafka
> hosts in the clients.